# Android ConstraintLayout ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT isn't working

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout, layoutparams

I try to add a ConstraintLayout programmatically. It's working but `WRAP_CONTENT` isn't working. The Layout is always `MATCH_PARENT`.

The Android Developer page doesn't list `WRAP_CONTENT` for [ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)

My Code:

```
RelativeLayout rl_main = findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
ConstraintLayout cl = new ConstraintLayout(this);
cl.setId(0);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams clp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_WRAP);
cl.setLayoutParams(clp);
cl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
rl_main.addView(cl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a view (`ConstrainLayout`) to `RelativeLayout` so You should use `RelativeLayout` params. Try this (also check if Your import is correct):

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout rl_main = findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        ConstraintLayout cl = new ConstraintLayout(this);
        cl.setId(0);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams clp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        cl.setLayoutParams(clp);
        cl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        rl_main.addView(cl);

        //test adding button
        cl.addView(new Button(this));
    }
}
```

Result (constraint layout with red background is `WRAP_CONTENT`):

[image]

Comment: Thank You. The problem is that I don't want to add a View inside the ConstraintLayout (Something will be added later.) When theres nothing inside the ConstraintLayout it's MATCH_PARENT (Not really MATCH_PARENT, because when I save the displayed xml code it's showing WRAP_CONTENT but the entire Layout is red...)

Comment: Oh, yeah I see it now. So You can just set visibility to `GONE` and after You add View change it to `VISIBLE`.